# Unable to build for Windows on Linux, with MinGW

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

Because I am not a Java enthusiast, I decided to use C++ and Qt for one of my projects. However, I came across the big **cross-compiling Qt** problem, and I am unable to produce an .exe file for Windows users.

#### My setup

Linux Ubuntu 12.04, with Wine and Qt. `qmake -v` gives the following output :

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

I also have a MinGW32 compiler, which can be found at `/usr/bin/i586-mingw32msvc-g++`. My Wine `drive_c` folder contains the following Qt directories :

```
$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/Src
$HOME/.wine/drive_c/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/mingw48_32
```

The `mingw48_32` directory contains the necessary `include/` and `lib/` directories, which are used in my mkspec file, `/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/win32-x-g++/qmake.conf` :

```
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /home/me/.wine/drive_c/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/mingw48_32/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /home/me/.wine/drive_c/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/mingw48_32/lib
```

#### The problem

According to most guides I've found about Qt cross-compiling, my setup should be enough to run a simple :

```
qmake -spec win32-x-g++
make
wine /path/to/my/application.exe
```

But... nothing's linked. `QApplication` and every other symbol I use in my program are "not found". No `QApplication`, no `QPushButton`, no `connect()`, no `SIGNAL()`, no `SLOT()`...

My objective here is to successfully configure QtCreator to use this setup (in an independent build configuration), so that it can build a Linux executable (through the first and working configuration), and a Win32 .exe (through the MinGW setup above). However, I cannot modify a single build step in QtCreator :

- Cannot add a "MinGW" toolchain : it is not available in the "Add" dropdown list.
- Cannot change the `-spec` parameter value in the project build configurations panel. The field is non-editable.

Despite guides and solutions I found all over the Internet, my only solution so far is to send my source code to a virtual Windows machine, and have it create a new project with it. On this VM, I could probably compile for Windows... But of course, this doesn't actually sound like a real "solution" to me...

Is there any way Qt(Creator) has finally made cross-compiling easier now ? I'm getting a bit tired of "symbol not found" errors...

Comment: it's too crazy to install QtCreator in wine ?

Comment: I'm a Linux user, and I wish to provide a Linux version as well (besides, I need QtCreator for Linux-only programs too). Wine is an accessory, so *yes*, it would be crazy to me. By the way, the VM idea is quite similar...

Comment: I develop in Ubuntu, and copy sources to Windows to recompile. Jan Wielemaker was able to setup a cross compiling environment when we worked on developing a Qt console for SWI-Prolog, but that was beyond my brain...He uses routinely cross-compiling to release Mac OS,Windows,Linux...

Comment: Then you're suggesting me to copy my project to a Win32 environment, which *is* the VM thingy... I'll do this if I cannot find a better solution. Qt is cross-platform, it should be providing an easier solution already...

Comment: As I said, the solution exists, but it's very complex. From what I understood, Jan used a precompiled setting of Qt...

Comment: MinGW can handle C++ cross-compilation. That's all about linking librairies correctly, isn't it ? Providing the DLLs is a Windows-specific manipulation, and yet, it blocks execution, *not compilation*. I know some people came accross a solution with a `mkspec` and Qt librairies in Wine, yet I cannot reproduce it... (see http://silmor.de/qtstuff.cross.php for instance). Anyway, I keep the VM trick in mind.

Answer (score 1):

First,

```
sudo apt-get install mingw-w64
```

Then, check if Qt Creator finds the toolchain.

Next, until Ubuntu starts providing a `mingw-w64-qt` package, download the Qt source and build it. This is bound to get messy, and maybe even the simplest thing to do is to [install WINE and use a Windows Qt version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38237/how-to-setup-qt-creator-to-compile-windows-executables).

Comment: I installed the `mingw-w64` package, and uninstalled the `mingw32` ones (they were in conflict). QtCreator still does not find a MinGW toolchain (GCC, Linux ICC, Clang, GCCE, RVCT, WINSCW but no MinGW).

Comment: @JohnWHSmith You can just point Qt Creator to `i686-w64-mingw32-g++` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++`.

Comment: Any help about this ? I added the new toolchain on `/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++`, but I can't use it as a project toolchain : Qt disables the "Tool chain" field (Build settings > General). Clicking Manage (and selecting the custom toolchain) doesn't change a thing : it remains on GCC...

Comment: You'll need a matching `qmake` if you're using a .pro based project, which is what the second part of my answer is about.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I have installed Qt libraries into Wine. The steps your link explains are pretty much what I did when I created my mkspec configuration. Still, I cannot use it (linking doesn't actually happen, QApplication and many other things are missing). Isn't it what you were talking about ?

Comment: Just install the Windows version of the Qt SDK in WINE, and use that. Or use a Linux distro that provides a cross-compiled Qt, like Fedora, OpenSUSE or Arch (through the AUR).